# SQLite Window function not running in google colab notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I am trying to run below code in google colab:

```
    #Get required Data
    data8 = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT  Person.Name, Person.Gender
    FROM M_Cast left JOIN Person USING (PID)
    WHERE PID NOT IN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT(PID) as PID
    FROM
        (
        SELECT *, LEAD(M_year, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Actor ORDER BY M_year ASC) AS N_Year
        FROM
            (
            SELECT trim(person.PID) as PID, trim(Person.Name) as Actor, substr(Movie.year,length(Movie.year)-3,4) as M_Year
            FROM Person
            LEFT JOIN M_Cast USING (PID)
            LEFT JOIN Movie USING (MID)
            )
        )
    WHERE (N_Year-M_Year)>3
    )''',con)

print('Output 8: Following is the list of actors never unemployed more than 3 years.(Included actors having single movie):\n')
data8
```

Colab throws me an error
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql
: near "(": syntax error

while its running well on my jupyter notebook

Comment: What is the line number of the code that‘s failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default sqlite version in Colab is 3.22, but window function is supported in 3.25+. So you need to upgrade it first

```
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:sergey-dryabzhinsky/packages
!apt update
!apt install sqlite3
```

Then restart runtime because sqlite is already loaded before.

```
MENU > Runtime > Restart runtime
```

Then check that it's a new version

```
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version) # 3.33.0
```

Comment: This does not work anymore in newer colab releases, unfortunately.

Comment: @simonst I have updated it to another ppa, so that it works again.